# Is there an "inventory mod" that doesn't allow cheating?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've used TMI and NEI *many* times in my SMP adventures, but I always find myself thinking "Well, I can just cheat in a few Stone to build this house. I mean.. I can get it easily anyhow so it's not *really* cheating." A little cheating opens the door to massive cheating like building entire structures in Creative mode and re-gifting myself items after dying.

So the question is, how can I use an inventory mod to look up recipes without that mod tempting me with a "cheat mode" button, or Creative mode toggle?

Comment: What do you mean by inventory mod? One that orders your inventory, or one that lists all of the items in the game and how to make them?

Comment: I mean one that shows recipes. See `how can I use an inventory mod to look up recipes.` I have a mod installed currently that sorts for me.

Comment: [You could always use your web browser.](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Crafting#Complete_recipe_list)

Comment: Yes, but NEI (and others) allows for recipes and uses for items added by mods.

Comment: Close voters closing as off-topic: This seems to be on-topic as per the top-voted answer in the ff: [meta] post, [Is “mod rec” really am umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja Recommendations, mod or otherwise, are strictly off-topic.  Unless there's an underlying problem that we can solve.  Then we re-word it to focus on THAT problem.

Comment: @fbueckert - The underlying problem is that he wants to see recipes in the game, without also having the ability to give himself any item from the game, because, unfortunately, NEI does both.  The last sentence seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @JasonBerkan That sounds like it would be pretty easy to re-word, then, to eliminate the mod request entirely.

Comment: @fbueckert - I think reading the section titled "Judge questions by the problem being posed instead of the presupposed answer." in [agent86's answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing/6830#6830) would be a good start to explaining why I do not agree with closing this nor do I think that editing to remove the mod request is required.

Comment: @fbueckert "*Recommendations, mod or otherwise, are strictly off-topic... we re-word it to focus on THAT problem.* "As per top-voted answer in the [meta] post, [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5548/4797): "*At worst, these are XY problems - the person has posted their problem and jumped to the assumption that the solution is modding the game. I don't really even see the need to revise these type of questions generally, as answers that solve the problem while ignoring the asker's suggested solution are still answers.*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NEI can be set to `Recipe Mode`. And if you think you'll still be too tempted to switch to cheat mode, open the file `%appdata%\.minecraft\config\NEI.cfg` and modify the following setting:

```
lockmode=0
```

This will make it impossible to switch to another mode ingame.

If you consider the ability to delete items (instead of having to burn them) no cheating, you could also set

```
lockmode=1
utility_actions=delete
```

to lock to utility mode, where the delete item icon is available in addition (I removed magnet, since that's already a cheat)

Comment: Nice! Does setting `lockmode` also get rid of the Creative button?

Comment: Yes, unless you lock to utility mode (=1) _and_ list `creative` in the `utility_actions`. There's a comment above the setting listing the possible utilities: `#Choose from time, creative, rain, item, heal, delete, magnet, enchant` (multiple possible when comma separated)

Comment: Great, will accept when I get this working. Never looked at the .cfg file :P

Comment: Btw, to add even more locks, you can change the file's owner to another user (e.g. Administrator) and give yourself only read permissions...

Comment: Also if he's using a bukkit server with Essentials installed he can do /recipe <item id/name>.

Comment: @user2104648 Good point, though as you mention it requires a bukkit server, which at least for single player would probably be overkill. But that reminds me I think NEI has a server side plugin that allows setting permissions for what parts of client side NEI are allowed and which are not

Comment: I'm pretty sure NEI just works by sending the command /give <player name> <item you clicked on> 64(if you right-clicked), if so the plugin would be any Permissions plugin, like PermissionsX or Bpermissions.

Comment: @user2104648 Yes and no. [There](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-147152-smp-chickenbones-mods/) is a server-side plugin (I don't remember if it's NEI itself or CodeChickenCore) that allows for additional NEI things like magnet mode and infinite stacks. But if it's not installed, then yes it's just `/give ...` and with permissions set accordingly cheating is also impossible